# Javascript: Submit form with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, submit, arrow-keys

I have four forms on a page, and I want any one of them submitted depending on which arrow key is pressed.

```
<form  name='go_north' action='' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='direction' value='north' />
</form>

<form  name='go_east' action='' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='direction' value='east' />
</form>

etc...
```

I can see how to do it with text inputs if they have focus, but I can't figure out how to do it with hidden inputs. Also, it only needs to work in Chrome. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the code? Something with [*KeyboardEvent.key*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `document.addEventListener("keydown", function(){})` which will listen for the keypresses, then determine the keycode and map them to submit the form based on the keycode.

Submitting the forms is as easy as finding the form and calling `.submit()` on it!

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  var code;
  if (event.key !== undefined) {
    code = event.key;
  } else if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
    code = event.keyIdentifier;
  } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
    code = event.keyCode;
  }
  console.log(code);
  handleArrow(code);
});

function handleArrow(code) {
  switch (code) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      submitForm('go_west');
      break;
    case 'ArrowRight':
      submitForm('go_east');
      break;
    case 'ArrowDown':
      submitForm('go_south');
      break;
    case 'ArrowUp':
      submitForm('go_north');
      break;
  }
}

function submitForm(id) {
  $("#" + id).submit();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="go_north">
  <label for="north">north</label>
  <input id="north" type="text" name="north" value="north">
</form>
<form id="go_east">
  <label for="east">east</label>
  <input id="east" type="text" name="east" value="east">
</form>
<form id="go_south">
  <label for="south">south</label>
  <input id="south" type="text" name="south" value="south">
</form>
<form id="go_west">
  <label for="west">west</label>
  <input id="west" type="text" name="west" value="west">
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#" + id).submit();` should probably be `document.forms[id].submit()`, I don't see a jQuery tag.